# Boid Particles come out above the mesh

Tags: particles, physics, collision

[image]

I'm trying to keep the boid particles confined in between the double wall of the house (behold image) but they keep coming out above or next to the plane itself.

When I move the plane away from the house object they come directly out of the mesh just fine. I have Collision Physics on the house.

Why are the particles not coming directly out of the plane inside the house? does it have something to do with the Collision Physics and how can i change that?

Comment: So you have a mesh object for the double-walled house, and a plane (another mesh) object, to emit the boid particles? If so, is the particle emitting plane position in between the two walls?

Comment: Yes, it is. the particle mesh is the orange line you see in the picture @Dazotaro